# Non negative integer triplets $(x,y,z)$ in $x^2+2y^2+4z^2+5=2(x+y+xy)+4z(y-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Non negative integer triplets $(x,y,z)$ in $x^2+2y^2+4z^2+5=2(x+y+xy)+4z(y-1)$

Try:  Writting equation as $$4z^2-4(y-1)z+x^2+2y^2-2(x+y+xy)+5=0$$

Now if equation has real roots. Then $$z=\frac{(y-1)\pm \sqrt{2xy+2x-x^2-y^2-4}}{2}$$

So for integer roots $2xy+2x-x^2-y^2-4=k^2$ , Where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So $$2x-(x+y)^2-4=k^2\Rightarrow (x+y)^2=2x-4-k^2$$

Now i did not understand how can i find non negative integer triplets $(x,y,z)$. Could some help me , Thanks

Comment: It isn't $(x+y)^2$ but $(x-y)^2$ in last line

Answer (score 2):

The discriminant was:

$$\begin{align}
2xy+2x-x^2-y^2-4&=k^2\\
\text{let} \qquad y=x \pm &t \\
2x(x \pm t)+2x-x^2-(x \pm t)^2-4&=k^2\\
2x^2 \color{red}{\pm 2tx}+2x-x^2-x^2 \color{red}{\mp 2tx}-t^2-4&=k^2 \\
2x-t^2-4&=k^2 \\
x&=\frac{1}{2}(k^2+t^2+4) \\
y=x\pm t&=\frac{1}{2}(k^2+t^2 \pm 2t+4) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[k^2+(t\pm 1)^2+3\right] \\
z=z=\frac{(y-1)\pm k}{2}&=\frac{\frac{1}{2}[k^2+(t\pm 1)^2+1] \pm k}{2} \\
&=\frac{(k\pm1)^2+(t\pm 1)^2}{4}
\end{align}$$

A solution set:

$$(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{2}\left(k^2+t^2+4,k^2+(t\pm 1)^2+3, \frac{(k\pm1)^2+(t\pm 1)^2}{2}\right)$$

It's apparent from $x$ and $y$ that both $k$ and $t$ should be the same parity, and it's apparent that from $z$ that that parity should be odd.  If 
$k=2m+1$ and $t=2n+1$ for $(m,n)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$:

$$\begin{align}
x&=\frac{1}{2}[(2m+1)^2+(2n+1)^2+4] \\
&=2m^2+2m+2n^2+2n+3 \\
\\
y&=\frac{1}{2}[(2m+1)^2+(2n+1\pm 1)^2+3] \implies \\
&\quad y_1=2m^2+2m+2(n+1)^2+2  \\
&\quad y_2=2m^2+2m+2n^2+2 \\
\\
z&=\frac{1}{4}[(2m+1\pm1)^2+(2n +1 \pm 1)^2] \implies \\
&\quad z_{(y_1,1)}=m^2+(n+1)^2 \\
&\quad z_{(y_1,2)}=(m+1)^2+(n+1)^2 \\
&\quad z_{(y_2,1)}=(m+1)^2+n^2 \\
&\quad z_{(y_2,2)}=m^2+n^2
\end{align}$$

To summarize:
$$\begin{align}
\text{for a given} \quad (m,n) &\to (x,y_1,z_{(y_1,1)}) \\
&\to (x,y_1,z_{(y_1,2)}) \\
&\to (x,y_2,z_{(y_2,1)}) \\
&\to (x,y_2,z_{(y_2,2)})
\end{align}$$

The bottom of Will Jagy's answer has the complete set of solutions, corresponding to these formulae

Comment: @WillJagy Re-requesting your review sir.....

Comment: looks promising; you do get $x \equiv 3 \pmod 4 $ ( I am referring to patterns in the computer output)  also $y$ even, and two $z$ values for each $(x,y)$ pair.

Comment: @WillJagy hmmmm yes on the latter two, trying to fig out why that's apparently true for $x$

Comment: @WillJagy nevermind it's right there basically...

Comment: You need a second set, with the same $x$ but $y$ replaced by the current $2x-y,$ then adjust $z$ if necessary. One of the patterns that is clear from the computer.... For example, you do get $x=3,y=4$ but miss the "reflected" $x=3, y=2$  Let me edit the beginning of what you have at the end of my answer...

Comment: @WillJagy maybe I should have made $y\to(x \color{red}{\pm} t)$ instead...

Comment: well, for now, work out the new triple and add that in in the same style. My first try gives $y = 2m^2 + 2m + 2 n^2 + 2$

Comment: @WillJagy indeed thank you... edited

Comment: For the new $y$ value, I get the revised $z$ values as $x-1-z$ for each, not quite the same as for your original $y$ value.

Comment: @WillJagy whoops I forgot to follow through.... I need to pair the $\pm$'s ....

Comment: I ran the simple program again with all four recipes. Looks very good, same (sometimes out of order) as the unrestricted Thursday output above it. At end of my answer.

Comment: @WillJagy how did you get the relation $y \to 2x -y $ ?  Notice a pattern in your solutions or was there a symmetry i didn't observe?

Comment: yes, noticed patterns in the computer ouput.

Answer (score 1):

$$  2y = 3 +(x-y-1)^2 + (y-2z-1)^2   $$

so the only impediment is odd/even. As $2y$ is even, we need $u^2 + v^2$ odd, where $u = x-y-1$ and $v = y-2z-1.$ However, then $u^2 + v^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ meaning $2y \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ and $y$ must be even. Then $v$ is automatically odd and we can solve for $z$ easily. Then $u$ must be even so $x$ must be odd.

So, change two letters, $x = 2m+1$ and $y = 2 n. $
$$  4n = 3 + (2m - 2n)^2 + (2n-2z -1)^2  $$
and gather as a quadratic in $n$ 
$$ 4n = 3 + 4m^2 - 8mn + 4 n^2 + 4 n^2 - 8 nz + 4 z^2 - 4 n + 4 z + 1  $$ 
$$ 0 = 8n^2 - (8m + 8z + 8)n + 4 m^2 + 4 z^2 + 4 z + 4  $$
$$  2n^2 - 2(m + z + 1)n +  m^2 +  z^2 +  z + 1 = 0  $$

I thought it worthwhile to get some solutions, without demanding anything positive, just integers. The problem was originally given as $$x^2+2y^2+4z^2+5=2(x+y+xy)+4z(y-1)$$

```
Thu May 24 15:02:56 PDT 2018
 x: 3 y: 2 z: 0 both sides equal :  22
 x: 3 y: 2 z: 1 both sides equal :  26
 x: 3 y: 4 z: 1 both sides equal :  50
 x: 3 y: 4 z: 2 both sides equal :  62
 x: 7 y: 4 z: 1 both sides equal :  90
 x: 7 y: 4 z: 2 both sides equal :  102
 x: 7 y: 6 z: 1 both sides equal :  130
 x: 7 y: 6 z: 4 both sides equal :  190
 x: 7 y: 8 z: 2 both sides equal :  198
 x: 7 y: 8 z: 5 both sides equal :  282
 x: 7 y: 10 z: 4 both sides equal :  318
 x: 7 y: 10 z: 5 both sides equal :  354
 x: 11 y: 8 z: 2 both sides equal :  270
 x: 11 y: 8 z: 5 both sides equal :  354
 x: 11 y: 14 z: 5 both sides equal :  618
 x: 11 y: 14 z: 8 both sides equal :  774
 x: 15 y: 10 z: 4 both sides equal :  494
 x: 15 y: 10 z: 5 both sides equal :  530
 x: 15 y: 14 z: 4 both sides equal :  686
 x: 15 y: 14 z: 9 both sides equal :  946
 x: 15 y: 16 z: 5 both sides equal :  842
 x: 15 y: 16 z: 10 both sides equal :  1142
 x: 15 y: 20 z: 9 both sides equal :  1354
 x: 15 y: 20 z: 10 both sides equal :  1430
 x: 19 y: 14 z: 5 both sides equal :  858
 x: 19 y: 14 z: 8 both sides equal :  1014
 x: 19 y: 16 z: 5 both sides equal :  978
 x: 19 y: 16 z: 10 both sides equal :  1278
 x: 19 y: 22 z: 8 both sides equal :  1590
 x: 19 y: 22 z: 13 both sides equal :  2010
 x: 19 y: 24 z: 10 both sides equal :  1918
 x: 19 y: 24 z: 13 both sides equal :  2194
 x: 27 y: 20 z: 9 both sides equal :  1858
 x: 27 y: 20 z: 10 both sides equal :  1934
 x: 27 y: 22 z: 8 both sides equal :  1958
 x: 27 y: 22 z: 13 both sides equal :  2378
 x: 27 y: 26 z: 9 both sides equal :  2410
 x: 27 y: 26 z: 16 both sides equal :  3110
 x: 27 y: 28 z: 10 both sides equal :  2702
 x: 27 y: 28 z: 17 both sides equal :  3458
 x: 27 y: 32 z: 13 both sides equal :  3458
 x: 27 y: 32 z: 18 both sides equal :  4078
 x: 27 y: 34 z: 16 both sides equal :  4070
 x: 27 y: 34 z: 17 both sides equal :  4202
 x: 31 y: 24 z: 10 both sides equal :  2518
 x: 31 y: 24 z: 13 both sides equal :  2794
 x: 31 y: 28 z: 10 both sides equal :  2934
 x: 31 y: 28 z: 17 both sides equal :  3690
 x: 31 y: 34 z: 13 both sides equal :  3954
 x: 31 y: 34 z: 20 both sides equal :  4878
 x: 31 y: 38 z: 17 both sides equal :  5010
 x: 31 y: 38 z: 20 both sides equal :  5454
 x: 39 y: 32 z: 13 both sides equal :  4250
 x: 39 y: 32 z: 18 both sides equal :  4870
 x: 39 y: 34 z: 13 both sides equal :  4514
 x: 39 y: 34 z: 20 both sides equal :  5438
 x: 39 y: 44 z: 18 both sides equal :  6694
 x: 39 y: 44 z: 25 both sides equal :  7898
 x: 39 y: 46 z: 20 both sides equal :  7358
 x: 39 y: 46 z: 25 both sides equal :  8258
 x: 43 y: 34 z: 16 both sides equal :  5190
 x: 43 y: 34 z: 17 both sides equal :  5322
 x: 43 y: 42 z: 16 both sides equal :  6406
 x: 43 y: 42 z: 25 both sides equal :  7882
 x: 43 y: 44 z: 17 both sides equal :  6882
 x: 43 y: 44 z: 26 both sides equal :  8430
 x: 47 y: 38 z: 17 both sides equal :  6258
 x: 47 y: 38 z: 20 both sides equal :  6702
 x: 47 y: 44 z: 17 both sides equal :  7242
 x: 47 y: 44 z: 26 both sides equal :  8790
 x: 47 y: 50 z: 20 both sides equal :  8814
 x: 47 y: 50 z: 29 both sides equal :  10578
Thu May 24 15:02:58 PDT 2018
```

===============================================================

all four recipes

```
Fri May 25 12:16:31 PDT 2018
        3        2        0     m  n          0        0
        3        2        1     m  n          0        0
        3        4        1     m  n          0        0
        3        4        2     m  n          0        0
        7       10        4     m  n          0        1
        7       10        5     m  n          0        1
        7        4        1     m  n          0        1
        7        4        2     m  n          0        1
        7        6        1     m  n          1        0
        7        6        4     m  n          1        0
        7        8        2     m  n          1        0
        7        8        5     m  n          1        0
       11       14        5     m  n          1        1
       11       14        8     m  n          1        1
       11        8        2     m  n          1        1
       11        8        5     m  n          1        1
       15       10        4     m  n          0        2
       15       10        5     m  n          0        2
       15       14        4     m  n          2        0
       15       14        9     m  n          2        0
       15       16       10     m  n          2        0
       15       16        5     m  n          2        0
       15       20       10     m  n          0        2
       15       20        9     m  n          0        2
       19       14        5     m  n          1        2
       19       14        8     m  n          1        2
       19       16       10     m  n          2        1
       19       16        5     m  n          2        1
       19       22       13     m  n          2        1
       19       22        8     m  n          2        1
       19       24       10     m  n          1        2
       19       24       13     m  n          1        2
       27       20       10     m  n          0        3
       27       20        9     m  n          0        3
```

Comment: Requesting your review of my answer, since it halfway depends on yours

Answer (score 0):

There is no way
$(x+y)^2+k^2=2x-4$ is giving you non negative values for $x,y.$
 Now looking on RHS we get that $2x-4$ will give least value at $x=2$.
Also we know that $x^2>mx$ iff $x>m$. ---(1)
Now as $y$ cant be negative and $k^2$ too can't be negative.
From $x^2>2x$ for all $x>2$ which is a contradiction as least value of $(x+y)^2$ is $x^2$ (as $x$ can't be less than $2$ but $y$ can be $0$)

Conclusion:It should be $(x-y)^2$ in last line of your problem

Comment: @WillJagy-I did mention that the asker had a calculation mistake in his last step of his approach. I wasn't saying it doesn't have any solution